Language proficiency level and word lists by Goethe-Institut
On this page we have a collection of lists of available resources to learn German.
Recently there was some activity on this question which addresses vocabulary lists corresponding to language proficiency levels, for which the resources page provides no information. Unfortunately it neither provides an answer, which can be easily extended to cover the links given in the accepted answer (and possibly some further links from comments).
Any proposal how to procede?
